# Nodes and text positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I want to use `tikz` to draw circle nodes with inside a text in math mode that has the following structure. A variable plus potentially a subscript and/or a superscript. I want the position of the variable within the circle to be exactly the same whether or not I add sub or superscript.

I have done the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,calc}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\supe}[1]{\smash{\mathrlap[\scriptstyle]{^{\ensuremath{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\indi}[1]{\smash{\mathrlap[\scriptstyle]{_{\ensuremath{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\suin}[2]{\smash{\mathrlap[\scriptstyle]{^{\ensuremath{#1}}_{\ensuremath{#2}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every circle node/.style={circle,draw,minimum height=1cm}]
\node [circle] (p) at (1,1) {$p$} ;
\node [circle,right=  of p]  (r1) {$p\indi{1}$} ;
\node [circle,right= of r1]  (r2) {$p\supe{2}$} ;
\node [circle,right= of r2]  (r3) {$r\suin{1}{3}$} ;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This seems to work well but I was wondering whether there is a more `tikz`-ian way to achieve the same result.

Comment: @PeterGrill This was exactly my question: how to use placement tricks in `tikz' to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a more TikZy way, but better LaTeX anyway:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,calc}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\supe}[1]{^{\smash{\mathrlap{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\indi}[1]{_{\smash{\mathrlap{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\suin}[2]{\supe{#1}\indi{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every circle node/.style={circle,draw,minimum height=1cm}]
\node [circle] (p) at (1,1) {$p$} ;
\node [circle,right=  of p]  (r1) {$p\indi{1}$} ;
\node [circle,right= of r1]  (r2) {$p\supe{2}$} ;
\node [circle,right= of r2]  (r3) {$r\suin{1}{3}$} ;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that in this way you're setting superscripts and subscripts where they belong, not to an empty formula as in your code.

[image]

Simpler version, same result:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,calc}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\fixedwidth}[2]{%
  \makebox[\widthof{$#1$}][l]{\vphantom{$#1$}\smash{$#1#2$}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every circle node/.style={circle,draw,minimum height=1cm}]
\node [circle] (p) at (1,1) {$p$} ;
\node [circle,right=  of p]  (r1) {\fixedwidth{p}{_1}} ;
\node [circle,right= of r1]  (r2) {\fixedwidth{p}{^2}} ;
\node [circle,right= of r2]  (r3) {\fixedwidth{r}{^1_3}} ;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not `tikz`-ian but most useful.

Answer (score 4):

I don' think there is anything specific built into `TikZ` to make this ask any easier. Perhaps you can use `TikZ` to do the placement to get this effect, but it certainly won't be any easier than achieving the same effect outside of `TikZ`.

But, I think you can do with just one macro:

```
\newcommand{\Smash}[1]{\smash{\mathrlap[\scriptstyle]{#1}}}
```

and comparing the output of your with just using `\Smash`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,calc}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\supe}[1]{\smash{\mathrlap[\scriptstyle]{^{\ensuremath{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\indi}[1]{\smash{\mathrlap[\scriptstyle]{_{\ensuremath{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\suin}[2]{\smash{\mathrlap[\scriptstyle]{^{\ensuremath{#1}}_{\ensuremath{#2}}}}}

\newcommand{\Smash}[1]{\smash{\mathrlap[\scriptstyle]{#1}}}

\begin{document}
Original version:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every circle node/.style={circle,draw,minimum height=1cm}]
\node [circle] (p) at (1,1) {$p$} ;
\node [circle,right=  of p]  (r1) {$p\indi{1}$} ;
\node [circle,right= of r1]  (r2) {$p\supe{2}$} ;
\node [circle,right= of r2]  (r3) {$r\suin{1}{3}$} ;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

Simplified version:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every circle node/.style={circle,draw,minimum height=1cm}]
\node [circle] (p) at (1,1) {$p$} ;
\node [circle,right=  of p]  (r1) {$p\Smash{_1}$} ;
\node [circle,right= of r1]  (r2) {$p\Smash{^2}$} ;
\node [circle,right= of r2]  (r3) {$r\Smash{^{1}_{3}}$} ;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice simplification!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something, I don't know exactly why this is not picked up but `text depth` is seemingly sufficient.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[
    every circle node/.style={
        draw,
        inner sep=2pt,
        text depth=0.45ex,
        text height=1.35ex,
        minimum size=1cm
    }
]
\node [circle] (p) at (1,1) {$p$};
\node [circle,right=  of p]  (r1) {$p_1$};
\node [circle,right= of r1]  (r2) {$p^2$};
\node [circle,right= of r2]  (r3) {$r_1^3$};
\node [circle,below= 3mm of p]  (r4) {$A_1^3$};
\node [circle,right= of r4]  (r5) {$M_M^M$};
\node [circle,right= of r5]  (r6) {$M_p^h$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With your solution the variable $p$ moves when going from the first node to the second. If you zoom, you will see $p$ excatly at the center in the first node but not so in the second.